# React - how map an array of objects and add a title without repeating and just showing each unique ttitle

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map out an array of objects in react but I'm stuck trying to map each entry.

```
const activities = [
  { value: "uniqueValue1", title: "Dancing", label: "Cha cha slide" },
  { value: "uniqueValue2", title: "Dancing", label: "Doing the salsa" },
  { value: "uniqueValue3", title: "Swimming", label: "Back stroke" },
  { value: "uniqueValue4", title: "Swimming", label: "Diving in the pool" },
  { value: "uniqueValue5", title: "Playing", label: "With toys" },
  { value: "uniqueValue6", title: "Playing", label: "With friends" },
]
```

and i'm looking to map each out into a checkbox to be selected:

```
<ul>
    {activityOptions.map(({ title, label }, index) => {
      return (
        <p key={index}>
          <div>
            <div>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                name={label}
                value={label}
                class="form-check-input"
                defaultValue={settingState.activity}
                onChange={(value) => {
                  setSettingState({...settingState, ...{ activity: value }});
                }}
                options={activityOptions}
                isDisabled={settingState.company}
              />
              <h6 htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{type}</h6>
              <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{label}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </p>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
```

how would I get it map collective titles rather than printing one per line?

```
Dancing: <--- h6 maybe
cha cha sldide <--- checkbox
doing the salsa

Swimming:
Back stroke
Diving in the pool

etc...
```

Rather than

```
Dancing:
cha cha slide
Dancing:
doing the salsa
Swimming:
Back stroke
Swimming:
Diving in the pool

etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it

```
const activities = [
  { value: "uniqueValue1", title: "Dancing", label: "Cha cha slide" },
  { value: "uniqueValue2", title: "Dancing", label: "Doing the salsa" },
  { value: "uniqueValue3", title: "Swimming", label: "Back stroke" },
  { value: "uniqueValue4", title: "Swimming", label: "Diving in the pool" },
  { value: "uniqueValue5", title: "Playing", label: "With toys" },
  { value: "uniqueValue6", title: "Playing", label: "With friends" }
];

const activityOptions = {};

activities.forEach(({ value, title, label }) => {
  let option = activityOptions[title];
  if (option) {
    activityOptions[title] = [...activityOptions[title], { value, label }];
  } else {
    activityOptions[title] = [{ value, label }];
  }
});

return (
  <ul>
    {Object.keys(activityOptions).map((id, index) => {
      const options = activityOptions[id];
      return (
        <li>
          <p key={index}>{id}</p>
          {options.map(({ type, label }) => (
            <div>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                name={id}
                value={id}
                class="form-check-input"
                defaultValue={settingState.activity}
                onChange={(value) => {
                  setSettingState({...settingState, ...{ activity: value }});
                }}
                options={options}
              />
                <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{label}</label>
            </div>
          ))}
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
);
```